# Disable some built-in functionality in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm developing a REST API backend application using Sails.js `0.10` as a framework. This application will be strictly REST, authentication will be implemented using oAuth bearer tokens. All responses will be in JSON format.

Considering this specific requirements I do not need some functionality embedded into Sails.js and I want to remove it from my application (so it will run faster without extraneous code).

So, my question is: How do I disable the following built-in functionality?

- Blueprints
- Static
- Cookies
- Sessions
- Views
- WebSocket
- CSRF
- i18n

What else can be disabled that is not required in my use case?

The documentation is kinda fragmented on this specific question. All configuration options are described for each module, but there is no information of how such a module can be disabled and/or removed from the application.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hardcore!  You'll need to disable several hooks, and also some middleware.  First, in your `.sailsrc` file, set:

```
"hooks": {
  "session": false,
  "sockets": false,
  "pubsub": false,
  "views": false,
  "csrf": false,
  "i18n": false,
  "blueprints": false
}
```

Then in your `config/https.js`:

```
middleware: {
  order: [
    'startRequestTimer',
    // 'cookieParser',
    // 'session',
    'bodyParser',
    'handleBodyParserError',
    'compress',
    'methodOverride',
    'poweredBy',
    '$custom',
    'router',
    // 'www',
    // 'favicon',
    '404',
    '500'      
  ]
}
```

That should get you on your way.

Comment: Thank you @sgress454! But, shouldn't middleware be disabled automatically when coresponding hooks are disabled? Is there something else I can disable to make my setup even lighter? Where I can find the full list and secription of built-in hooks and middlewares? Is there a documentation for this? Thanks again!

Comment: The Express middleware and Sails hooks and are kept separate intentionally.  The former provide extra low-level functionality, mainly by adding to the `req` and `res` objects or the Express router.  The latter extends Sails functionality by making things more configurable or adding new features.  Middleware are listed in the Sails docs [here](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Middleware); there's not a good doc for the default hooks right now, although most of the features they represent have their own doc sections.

Comment: I see, thank you for explanation. Is it also possible to disable Static middleware: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Assets?q=static-middleware and Blueprints? I'm writing an article while configuring the application. I think my experience with this will be a good contribution to the community = )

Comment: @SlavaFominII you can use the skipAssets routing option: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes#?route-target-options

Comment: @sgress454 do you have an answer for this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838905/sails-js-remove-bodyparser-middleware-for-a-specific-route