# Sails.js :remove bodyparser middleware for a specific route

Tags: node.js, sails.js, body-parser

Is there any way to remove middleware for a particular route

currently all the middlewares are listed in `http.js` file

```
[
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'bodyParser',
      'passportInit',
      'passportSession',
      'myRequestLogger',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
  ]
```

I want to remove the `bodyParser` middleware for a particular route

Is it possible with sails.js??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no mechanism for doing this declaratively, but yes, you can disable a middleware on a per-route basis.  You would do it by overriding the middleware and checking the route URL within your custom code, similar to the solution for [using a separate body parser for XML requests](https://github.com/sails101/use-xml-body-parser/blob/master/config/http.js).  For example:

```
// In config/http.js `middleware` property

bodyParser: (function() {
  // Initialize a skipper instance with the default options.
  var skipper = require('skipper')();
  // Create and return the middleware function.
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // If we see the route we want skipped, just continue.
    if (req.url === '/dont-parse-me') {
      return next();
    }
    // Otherwise use Skipper to parse the body.
    return skipper(req, res, next);
  };
})()
```

That's the basic idea.  It could certainly be done a bit more elegantly; for example if you had several routes you wanted skipped, you could save the list in a separate file and check the current URL against that list.

Comment: So do I need to call the bodyParser middleware in order array

Comment: It's already in there by default.  If you have a customized `order` array then yes, you need to make sure `bodyParser` is in there in order for this solution to work.

Comment: So here i am overriding the default bodyParser middleware am i right??

Comment: That's right, although for most routes the code above will still use Skipper which is what normally happens by default.